# White Space Around Images in Bootstrap IMG Gallery

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://seattleasce.org/images/test_gallery/ymf_history.php

I'm working on this site and have been trying to remove the extra white space between images. I'm using bootstrap and the bootstrap image gallery libraries, and can't seem to figure out how to fix this. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is `a` elements are inherently `inline-block` which has a natural padding of about 1 or 2px. There are some hacks to remove the spacing but it's better practice to use `float: left` instead. Just be sure to clear your floats or add `overflow: hidden` to their parent.

EX:

```css
/*CSS*/

.SomeClassName{
  display: block;      
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<a href=" /images/test_gallery/IMG_0422.JPG " data-gallery="" class="SomeClassName"> 
  <img width="100px" src=" /images/test_gallery/resize/IMG_0422.JPG ">
</a>
```

Comment: So you're saying that if I applied the CSS attributes float: left and overflow: hidden I should be able to remove the space? I tried that but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I checked and you already have a clearfix on the parent so don't worry about the `overflow: hidden`. I would suggest you add a class to all of the `a` tags that are wrapping those images (you dont want to float all `a`'s on the page) and then add `float: left` to that class.

Comment: I would also recommend including `display: block` in that class that you tack on so the `a` tags aren't collapsed

Comment: @EricK no problem. Glad to help. Can you just check this off as resolved?